# Angular $q.all() combine the previous operation with current operation

Tags: angularjs, q

Because code is too complex, i can only paste the structure of the code:

```
angular.module('xxx').controller('xxxCtrl', ['$scope', ..., '$q', function($scope, ..., $q){
    ...

    //every checked unchecked event in multi-checkbox trigger the change in measurement
    $scope.$watch('measurement', function (newValue, oldValue) {

        pendingRequests = {
                    primary: $q.defer(),
                    ...: $q.defer()
                };

        var promises = _.map(pendingRequests, function (deferred) {
                return deferred.promise;
            });

        $q.all(promises).then(function (results) {

            $scope.data = results[0];
            $window.console.log($scope.data);


        });

        //Here i have a $http request to server
        ResultService.requestResultsOnce();
    });

}])
```

The scenario is like this, we have multiple checkboxes on the page, every change to the multi-checkboxes will trigger the watch method.

If i click the checkbox with normal speed, it works perfect.

But if i click 2 checkboxes with very fast speed, the callback in

```
$q.all(promises).then
```

will be called only once.

Does anyone can help on this?

Actually the every $http success callback is correctly executed 2 times, why the then method execute only 1 time?

It seems $q.all combine the last time request with the new click request.

Comment: Because as your logic is implemented.. All pending promises are putted into the promises array.

Comment: @pankajparkar I don't get it, why i slowly click two checkboxes, it work well. Do you have any solution for this?